# Create EditorTemplate for a ViewModel instead of a CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, editorfor

Instead of using a CheckBoxList helper control I want to use the editor templates of the mvc framework:

In Shared\EditorTemplate I have TemplateViewModel.cshtml

```
@model ITMS.ViewModels.TemplateViewModel

<p class="checkbox">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) 
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
</p>
```

As the template must have the same name as the view model... here we go:

```
public class TemplateViewModel
{  
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string Name { get; set; }   
}
```

In Home\Delete.cshtml I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<ITMS.ViewModels.TemplateViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item)   
}
```

The output in the Delete.cshtml is a total mess.

I just want that my check-status and name is visible and the id is hidden somewhere.

How do I correct my TemplateViewModel.cshtml/Delete.cshtml ?

Comment: "is a total mess" is meaningless.  Describe your problem in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Delete.cshtml` get rid of the foreach loop and simply:

```
@model IEnumerable<ITMS.ViewModels.TemplateViewModel>
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

The editor template will automatically be rendered for each element of your model (which in this case is a collection) and you don't need to write any loops.

Also make sure that your editor template is in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TemplateViewModel.cshtml`. In your question you wrote `Shared\EditorTemplate` which is a wrong location (you forgot an `s` at the end). Templates work by conventions that you must follow.

Comment: thanks Darin works, but I just thought why should I choose this approach with EditorTemplates and not just annotate my viewmodel with DataTypes? Or another similar approach. Why the EditorTemplate ?

Comment: @Pascal, I understand what you mean by annotating the view model with DataTypes and what this has to do with the custom editor template that you have written. The main benefit of editor templates is that they simplify your view code and generate proper names for your input fields so that the default model binder is able to deserialize the values back.